# A NN based model of a Cattle for 'Heat Detection'

Tags: machine-learning, ai-design, classification, training, models

I am very new to AI/ML but have lot of interest in these. I am trying to understand how [this](https://www.fujitsu.com/jp/group/kyushu/en/solutions/industry/agriculture/gyuho/feature/) gadget works.

[image: Wearable device features]

So far I have understood that a NN model of the cattle is generated by offline classification of the tagged data which is received from the wearable sensor. Consequently some ML algorithms are used to generate a model of a cattle.

That model is then embedded in the programmable wearable device. The device then sends the real-time tagged (classified, parameterized) data to the server.

Now I am looking for a sample NN-model of a cattle. I wonder how does a NN-model of a cattle would look like?

Comment: It's an old question and so far no answer to it. Does it mean that NN models for cattle are not possible?